# Multiline variables in Pug (ex-Jade)

Tags: html, web, pug, pugjs

Is it possible to use it? For example here:

```jade
- var movieList = [{title: "Ocean's Eleven", rating: 9.2}, {title: "Pirates of the Caribbean", rating: 9.7}];

mixin movie-card(movie)
  h2.movie-title= movie.title
  div.rating
    p= movie.rating

for movie in movieList
  +movie-card(movie)
```

I don't want to use `-` at the start of each line.
If it not possible maybe there is some way to import multiline JSON file?

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't be implemented until somebody proposes a pull request: https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/796

Answer (score 8):

Since version 2.0.3 it is possible using this syntax:

```
-
  var arr = ["Very", "Long",
             "Array"];
```

Link to pull request: https://github.com/pugjs/pug/pull/1965

Answer (score 2):

You can import JSON data during [compile](http://jade-lang.com/api/) using LOCALS (Jade) or DATA (Pug). This is how I do it via gulpjs and Pug, movieList would be data created in the gulpfile.js and songs.json would be an external file. It's not clear from you code sample if you are using a task manager or express, etc...

gulpfile.js

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    pug = require('gulp-pug'),
    movieList = [{title: "Ocean's Eleven", rating: 9.2}, {title: "Pirates of the Caribbean", rating: 9.7}];

gulp.task('markup', function() {
  gulp.src('./markup/*.pug')
    .pipe(pug({
      data: {
      // in Jade, this would be "locals: {"
        "movies": movieList,
        "music": JSON.parse( fs.readFileSync('./songs.json', { encoding: 'utf8' }) )
      }
    )
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../'))
  });
});
```

and in the Pug Template

```
- var movieList = locals['movies'] // assuming this will eventually be "= data['movies']"
- var musicList = locals['music'] // assuming this will eventually be "= data['music']"

mixin movie-card(movie)
  h2.movie-title= movie.title
  div.rating
    p= movie.rating

for movie in movieList
  +movie-card(movie)

mixin song-card(song)
  h2.song-title #{song.title}
  div.rating
    p #{song.rating}

for song in musicList
  +song-card(song)
```